# Is there any way to make scripts dynamic?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I need my script to show the time till next run, continuously like a timer, is this possible?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, how script is triggered? what is the content of the script ?

Comment: Time till **next** run? If you want to predict the future event then you may want to first read about [Einstein–Rosen bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole#Schwarzschild_wormholes) and later on implement it in `bash` script.

Comment: @klerk Contents are about the last run details of most of the jobs in cron and time left till their the next run would occur

Comment: @jimmij - We for sure would be knowing the next run's time, won't we? Costas received it well!

Comment: @Keys If exact date of next run is defined that's different story. :)

Comment: @jimmij Maybe I should've added about the `cron` in the question  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a lot of the work w/ shell math so you don't have to fork every few seconds, but you probably would want to work in some sort of synchronizer every once in a while to ensure the time is keeping well.

The below loop just sets some initial values for `$h`, `$m`, and `$s` then decrements once every 15 seconds and prints a countdown line at the top-left hand of the terminal screen *(row 1, column 1, `\033[Home`)*. You can background it without issue, but you'd probably want to safe it with other `trap`s first if it were to run for awhile.

```
(h=23 m=1 s=60; trap '' TTOU
until [ "$(((h-=(!(m-=!(s-=s?15:-45)*(m?1:-59))&&!s))+m+s))" -eq 0 ]
do    sleep 15
      printf "\0337\033[H\033[KT- %02d : %02d : %02d\0338" \
             "$h" "$((m?m:60))" "$((s?s:60))"
done) &
```

The line it prints looks like this top one here...

```
T- 22 : 49 : 60 
130 mikeserv@localhost ~ %       
130 mikeserv@localhost ~ %       
130 mikeserv@localhost ~ % (     
h=23 m=1 s=60; trap '' TTOU
```

I actually forgot it was still running, but it will continue to draw over the same place if the terminal doesn't scroll, like this...

```
T- 22 : 48 : 30 
130 mikeserv@localhost ~ %       
130 mikeserv@localhost ~ %       
130 mikeserv@localhost ~ % (     
h=23 m=1 s=60; trap '' TTOU
```

But if the terminal does scroll its line will be scrolled off the screen until at most 15 seconds elapse and it prints another. The escapes used are commonly interpreted as `sc` *(savecursor: `\0337`)*, `hr` *(home row: `\033[H`)*, `kl` *(kill line: `\033[K`)* and `rc` *(restore cursor: `\0338`)*. If any of these do not work for you you should check with `tput` for their values. Basically the cursor position is first saved, then moved to the top of the terminal screen, the top line is erased, and the countdown is printed. The cursor position is restored.

It works by balancing the decrements.

Like...

```
 h - !(m - !(s - s < 60 ? 15 : -45 ) && !s )
```

...there's a little more to it than that, but the method is only to subtract one from a larger value when a smaller value decrements to 0. So when the seconds value decrements from 1 to 0 the minutes value also decrements - and when *both* minutes and seconds are zero, so also does the hours value decrement.

When the loop completes... nothing happens. I don't really know what you want done, but whatever it is, you should tuck it in after the `done` there.

You should be able to start `$h` `$m` and `$s` at pretty much any value, but, as written, the `$s`econds value is expected to decrement in 15 second intervals *(though that is easily altered)*. Anyway, just keep that in mind.

Comment: `-bash-3.2$^[7 ^[[H^[[KT- 22 : 59 : 15 ^[8^[7 ^[[H^[[KT- 22 : 58 : 60 ^[8^[7 ^[[H^[[KT- 22 : 58 : 45 ^[8^[7 ^[[H^[[KT- 22 : 58 : 30 ^[8^[7 ^[[H^[[KT- 22 : 58 : 15 ^[8^[7 ^[[H^[[KT- 22 : 57 : 60 ^[8^[7 ^[[H^[[KT- 22 : 57 : 45 ^[8^[7 ^[[H^[[KT- 22 : 57 : 30 ^[8^[7 ^[[H^[[KT- 22 : 57 : 15 ^[8^[7 ^[[H^[[KT- 22 : 56 : 60 ^[8
-bash-3.2$ ^[7 ^[[H^[[KT- 22 : 56 : 45 ^[8` Its not being placed where you expected it to be, it isn't following the sequences for the position you mentioned, Bash is 3.2

Comment: @Keys - it looks like you're using the literal characters `^[`. Sorry - I should have mentioned that - those are just the terminal's visual representation for them. They're actually the `ESC` nonprinting character. I entered it by pressing `CTRL+V` then `ESC` - which is why it shows the `^[` the ESC notation, but you could also use *(w/ `printf`)* `\033` as mentioned. On the bright side, it looks the math is right... hehe. Actually mine is still runnning: `T- 09 : 10 : 45` which is at least close to the *answered 13 hours ago* note next to my name there.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, trying with printf now, hung it up with `fg` and `Ctrl+C` :)

Comment: @Keys - If you background this then until you background another process you can reference the subshell's pid in `$!` - which is a special POSIX shell parameter that expands to the PID of the most recently backgrounded process. You can save that - like `countdown=$!` - and kill it whenever you like with `kill "$countdown"`. Fair warning: `bash` does stupid, insane things w/ `!` though, so you might want to do *(on a separate command line)* `set +H` first.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
t=1
until [ "$t" -le 0 ]
do
    t=$(($(date -d '2015-02-24 16:40:00' +'%s')-$(date +'%s')))
    sleep 1
    tput clear
    echo $t
done
```

Comment: Instead of `tput clear` you may want to overwrite previous value with `echo -ne "\r$t"`

Comment: @jimmij Better `printf '% 8d\r' $t`